# Substring replace in ActionScript 2

Tags: string, actionscript-2, substring, replace

I primarily work with AS3 when dealing with flash, but I have a need to use AS2 for a particular project, AS2 is not my friend.

I need to replace a series of substrings within some data on a regular basis.  Normally I would create a cleaning function that utilised `string.replace()` and run my data through it.

However the `string.replace()` function is missing from AS2 and I haven't found an equivalent.  What would be the simplest method for achieving similar functionality?

example:

```
dirtydata = "I have ABCtoast withABCABC jamABC"
```

my result would be:

```
cleandata = "I have toast with jam"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this,

```
String.prototype.replace = function(searchStr, replaceStr):String { 
    var arr:Array = this.split(searchStr);
    return arr.join(replaceStr);
};  

// initial string with a placeholder
var str:String = 'I have ABCtoast withABCABC jamABC';
// replace ABC with '' and trace it
var replacedStr:String = str.replace('ABC','');
trace(replacedStr)
```

Else, you could also go for a function performing split and join on the same line.

```
function stringReplace(block:String, find:String, replace:String):String
{
return str.split(searchStr).join(replaceStr);
}
```